# iid RVs and finding $\lim_{n\to\infty} \text{Pr}(|\frac{\eta_n}{\sqrt{n}}|<2m)$ given $0<\lim_{n\to\infty} \text{Pr}(|\frac{\eta_n}{\sqrt{n}}|<m)=k$

Tags: probability

If you have iid RVs $\xi_1,\xi_2 \cdots $ such that $\mathbb{E}(\xi_k)=0$ and $\text{Var}(\xi_k)<\infty $

Further for $m,n$ (larger than zero)

$0<\lim_{n\to\infty} \text{Pr}(|\frac{\eta_n}{\sqrt{n}}|<m)=k$

I need to find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \text{Pr}(|\frac{\eta_n}{\sqrt{n}}|<2m)$

Am I able to use anything like:

$\displaystyle\frac{\eta_n}{\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}} c$ ($c$ is constant) which then implies $\displaystyle\frac{\eta_n}{\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{p}c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hypotheses guarantee that the CLT holds hence $P[|\eta_n|\lt x\sigma\sqrt{n}]\to2\Phi(x)-1$ for every $x\geqslant0$, with $\sigma^2=\mathrm{var}(X_n)$.

Thus, $k=2\Phi(m/\sigma)-1$ and $P[|\eta_n|\lt 2m\sqrt{n}]\to\ell$ with $\ell=2\Phi(2m/\sigma)-1$. Equivalently,
$$
\ell=2\Phi\left(2\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{k+1}2\right)\right)-1.
$$